# Assigning symbol to variable result in nil

Tags: ruby, symbols

I'm attempting to assign a symbol to a variable and pass that into a function, however it doesn't seem to assign, I get `nil` instead

```
  logger.info @payload['branch_name']
  logger.info @payload['branch_name'].to_sym
  branch_name = @payload.has_key? 'branch_name' ? @payload['branch_name'].to_sym : false;
  logger.info branch_name
```

Results in:

```
[2015-02-18T12:53:01.237082 #6]  INFO -- : develop
[2015-02-18T12:53:01.237154 #6]  INFO -- : :develop
[2015-02-18T12:53:01.237234 #6]  INFO -- : nil
```

But I would have expected it to assign the symbol to the variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to fix the parentheses because of operator precedence (e.g. the ternary operator `?` is evaluated before `has_key?`). Try this instead:

```
branch_name = @payload.has_key?('branch_name') ? @payload['branch_name'].to_sym : false;
```

The behaviour can be reproduced with the following example snippet:

```
a = { 2 => 2 }
=> {2=>2}
a.has_key?­ 1 ? 2 : 3 # 1 evalutes to true, which reduces into a.has_key?(2)
=> true
```

Comment: Totally spot on @matt! Thanks a lot!